Github Actions & Yarn: Invalid resolution json5@npm:^2.2.2 → npm:1.0.2
It works on my local, but yarn install fails on github actions.
I have setup Node and yarn version same as my project
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: "20"
          cache: 'yarn'

      - name: Enable Corepack
        run: corepack enable
      - name: Set Yarn version
        run: corepack prepare yarn@4.3.1 --activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: yarn install

But, error occured.
Run yarn install
➤ YN0000: Yarn detected that the current workflow is executed from a public pull request. For safety the hardened mode has been enabled.
➤ YN0000: It will prevent malicious lockfile manipulations, in exchange for a slower install time. You can opt-out if necessary; check our documentation for more details.
➤ YN0000: · Yarn 4.3.1
➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
Resolution step
➤ YN0078: Invalid resolution json5@npm:^2.2.2 → npm:1.0.2
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 11s 745ms
➤ YN0000: · Failed with errors in 11s 757ms
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I used these methods

package.json resolution field, I set json5 to 2.2.2
yarn install --immutable
on the other way,

env:
  YARN_ENABLE_IMMUTABLE_INSTALLS: false


yarn add json5 2.2.2 version directly
But they don't work.

What causes this and how do I fix it?
There is no problem in other environments such as dev
I solve this with env option.
env:
  YARN_ENABLE_HARDENED_MODE: 0

But I know this is never good for security and I'm wondering how to avoid using this.

Hardened Mode
As you have identified, this is due to Yarn automatically enabling Hardened Mode for security reasons.
Without Hardened Mode, you may be vulnerable to a supply chain attack known as lockfile poisoning, where an outside contributor opens a pull request that modifies both package.json and yarn.lock. Because of the dependencies change in package.json, a modification to the lockfile is expected and does not raise suspicion. In reality, the attacker has tampered with the lockfile to force one of the dependencies to resolve to something else, like a GitHub repo they control. This in turn allow the attacker to run arbitrary code on other developers' machines.
Hardened Mode is designed to protect against this by checking the resolutions in the lockfile to see if they "make sense", so to speak. Yarn uses a heuristic to determine if yarn install is being run on untrusted code and automatically enables Hardened Mode if so.
In your case, a package requested as ^2.2.2 resolving to version (1.0.2) that does not satisfy the semver constraint is flagged as potentially malicious.
Solution
If json5@npm:^2.2.2 resolving to 1.0.2 is intended, then you need to tell Yarn that by adding resolution to your package.json:
   "dependencies": {
     "json5": "^2.2.2"
+  },
+  "resolutions": {
+    "json5@npm:^2.2.2": "1.0.2"
   }

then running a yarn install (locally) will update the lockfile to reflect this:
-"json5@npm:^2.2.2":
+"json5@npm:1.0.2":
   version: 1.0.2
   resolution: "json5@npm:1.0.2"
   dependencies:


If json5@npm:^2.2.2 resolving to 1.0.2 is NOT intended, then you need to fix the lockfile by running yarn up -R json5 (locally) to re-resolve json5.
